# Homotopy coherent nerve for algebraic model categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, model-categories, infinity-categories

Is a homotopy coherent nerve defined for algebraic model category that returns algebraic quasi-categories as Urs Schreiber [wrote about](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2010/06/algebraic_model_structures.html#c033531)? Or do we not know how to determine it / does it seem impossible?

I did not quite understand: perhaps the comments that Mike Shulman gave in response(see link) are an insurmountable obstacle to defining this concept? Since at least September 2011 we have a monoidal algebraic model structure on the category of simplicial sets ([Emily Riehl - Monoidal algebraic model structures](https://emilyriehl.github.io/files/monoidal.pdf))